# Material UI Rating: How to change styles to odd icons

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React and Material UI components. Due to design specs I need to change margins for odd icons inside Rating component. I tried to add something like this `"&.MuiRating-root:{ &:nth-child(odd)}"` and `"&.MuiRating-icon:{&:nth-child(odd)}"` to the classname applied to the icons but have no results.
How can I achieve this?

Here are the classes applied to the Rating component:

```css
narrativeWeightBar: {
        "& .MuiRating-iconHover": {
            transform: "none",
            "& $narrativeWeightPill": {
                backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.light,
            },
        },

        "& .MuiRating-iconFilled": {
            "& $narrativeWeightPill": {
                backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
            },
            "&.MuiRating-iconHover": {
                "& $narrativeWeightPill": {
                    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
                },
            },
        },

        "&.MuiRating-readyOnly": {
            "& $narrativeWeightPill": {
                boxShadow: "none",
            },
        },
    },
    
    narrativeWeightPill: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.neutrals.light,
        width: "100%",
        maxWidth: 100,
        minWidth: 40,
        height: 8,
        borderRadius: theme.spacing(1, 0, 0, 1),
        marginRight: 5,
        boxShadow: "inset 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55)",
    },
```

And this is where those classes are applied:

```js
const customRatingItem = Array.from(Array(11)).map((item, i) => {
        return (
            <Box
                key={new Date().toISOString()}
                className={cn(classes.narrativeWeightPill, { [classes.narrativeWeightPillInverse]: ++i % 2 !== 0 })}
            />
        );
    });

    return (
        <Box
            className={cn(classes.narrativeItem, {
                [classes.narrativeSelected]: !item.id.includes("narrative_"),
            })}
        >
            <Typography className={classes.narrativeLabel}>{item.label}</Typography>
            <Box className={classes.narrativeWeightBarWrapper}>
                {index === 0 && (
                    <Box className={classes.narrativeBarLabels}>
                        <Typography>Lower Importance</Typography>
                        <Typography>Higher Importance</Typography>
                    </Box>
                )}
                <Rating
                    className={classes.narrativeWeightBar}
                    name="narrative-weight-bar"
                    max={customRatingItem.length}
                    value={item.weight}
                    readOnly={item.id.includes("narrative_")}
                    IconContainerComponent={({ value, ...other }) => <span {...other}>{customRatingItem[value]}</span>}
                    onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                        selectedPreSettedVcp.current = undefined;
                        setNarratives((currentValues) =>
                            currentValues.map((current) =>
                                current.id === item.id ? { ...current, weight: Number(newValue) } : current
                            )
                        );
                    }}
                />
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );
```

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.